# Jupyter notebook truncates value inside of individual cells (not rows or columns, but the text)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, formatting, settings

Python 3.9.10
notebook==6.4.8
Linux VERSION="22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)"

I have data including very long UUID strings. Regardless of how many rows or columns are being shown in the Jupyter output, the **long UUID strings are being truncated in *each individual cell***...

I.e.

```
97bd13ed-e982-482a-9fab-23fc3e588dfd_b207580a-d8bc-4fce-b125-699b03973116
```

...appears as...

[image: Truncated string in cell]

**Is there a setting to allow the full string to appear in the cell?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see all the full text, you could use `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)`

or if you want to have this for only one display:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', None):
    display(df)
```